Nsis problem: Error in macro GetVersion on macroline 14
I have been having this issue for a while and just cant figure it out. I would be eternaly gratefull if someone could help me with it. This is the error:
Usage: StrCpy $(user_var: output) str [maxlen] [startoffset]
Error in macro GetVersion on macroline 14
Error in script "C:\zzalles\Output\Dr.WebApi\Dr.WebApi.nsi" on line 48 -- aborting creation process
I think its referring to this:
!macro GetVersion FILE VERSION
    System::Call 'kernel32::GetFileVersionInfoSize(t "${FILE}", *i .R1)'
    System::Alloc 256
    Pop $R2
    System::Call 'kernel32::GetFileVersionInfo(t "${FILE}", i R1, i 256, *i $R2)'
    System::Call 'version::GetFileVersionInfoSize(t "${FILE}", *i .R1)'
    System::Alloc 256
    Pop $R2
    System::Call 'version::GetFileVersionInfo(t "${FILE}", i R1, i 256, *i $R2)'
    System::Call 'version::VerQueryValue(i $R2, t "\\", *i .R3, *i .R4)'
    System::Alloc 1024
    Pop $R2
    System::Call 'version::VerQueryValue(i $R3, t "\FileVersion", *i .R2, *i .R4)'
    System::Call '*$R2(t, i, R2)'
    StrCpy $VERSION $R2 256 ; Added the missing input string and the maximum length
    System::Free $R2
!macroend

This is the complete script if needed:
!define APP_NAME "Dr.WebApi"
!define COMP_NAME "DRGT Systems GmbH"
!define VERSION "00.00.00.00"
!define COPYRIGHT "DRGT"
!define DESCRIPTION ""
!define INSTALLER_NAME "..\Output\Dr.WebApi\setup.exe"
!define MAIN_APP_EXE "Dr.WebApi.exe"
!define INSTALL_TYPE "SetShellVarContext current"
!define REG_ROOT "HKCU"
!define REG_APP_PATH "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\${MAIN_APP_EXE}"
!define UNINSTALL_PATH "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${APP_NAME}"

!define REG_START_MENU "Start Menu Folder"

var SM_Folder
var SILENT

######################################################################

Section "Preparation"
!macro GetVersion FILE VERSION
    System::Call 'kernel32::GetFileVersionInfoSize(t "${FILE}", *i .R1)'
    System::Alloc 256
    Pop $R2
    System::Call 'kernel32::GetFileVersionInfo(t "${FILE}", i R1, i 256, *i $R2)'
    System::Call 'version::GetFileVersionInfoSize(t "${FILE}", *i .R1)'
    System::Alloc 256
    Pop $R2
    System::Call 'version::GetFileVersionInfo(t "${FILE}", i R1, i 256, *i $R2)'
    System::Call 'version::VerQueryValue(i $R2, t "\\", *i .R3, *i .R4)'
    System::Alloc 1024
    Pop $R2
    System::Call 'version::VerQueryValue(i $R3, t "\FileVersion", *i .R2, *i .R4)'
    System::Call '*$R2(t, i, R2)'
    StrCpy $VERSION $R2 256 ; Added the missing input string and the maximum length
    System::Free $R2
!macroend



    ; Perform version retrieval
    !insertmacro GetVersion "${MAIN_APP_EXE}" VERSION

    VIProductVersion  "${VERSION}"
    VIAddVersionKey "ProductName"  "${APP_NAME}"
    VIAddVersionKey "CompanyName"  "${COMP_NAME}"
    VIAddVersionKey "LegalCopyright"  "${COPYRIGHT}"
    VIAddVersionKey "FileDescription"  "${DESCRIPTION}"
    VIAddVersionKey "FileVersion"  "${VERSION}"
SectionEnd

######################################################################

SetCompressor ZLIB
Name "${APP_NAME}"
Caption "${APP_NAME}"
OutFile "${INSTALLER_NAME}"
BrandingText "${APP_NAME}"
XPStyle on
InstallDirRegKey "${REG_ROOT}" "${REG_APP_PATH}" ""
InstallDir "$PROGRAMFILES\Dr.WebApi"

######################################################################

!include "MUI.nsh"

!define MUI_ABORTWARNING
!define MUI_UNABORTWARNING

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME

!ifdef LICENSE_TXT
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "${LICENSE_TXT}"
!endif

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY

!ifdef REG_START_MENU
!define MUI_STARTMENUPAGE_NODISABLE
!define MUI_STARTMENUPAGE_DEFAULTFOLDER "Dr.WebApi"
!define MUI_STARTMENUPAGE_REGISTRY_ROOT "${REG_ROOT}"
!define MUI_STARTMENUPAGE_REGISTRY_KEY "${UNINSTALL_PATH}"
!define MUI_STARTMENUPAGE_REGISTRY_VALUENAME "${REG_START_MENU}"
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_STARTMENU Application $SM_Folder
!endif

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES

!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN "$INSTDIR\${MAIN_APP_EXE}"
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH

!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_CONFIRM

!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_INSTFILES

!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_FINISH

!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"

######################################################################

Function .onInit
    ${If} $CMDLINE ~ "/S"
        StrCpy $SILENT 1
    ${EndIf}
FunctionEnd

Section -MainProgram
${INSTALL_TYPE}
SetOverwrite ifnewer
SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\appsettings.7OF9.json"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\appsettings.CUBE.json"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\appsettings.Graz.json"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\appsettings.grz-dev-srv03.json"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\appsettings.json"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\appsettings.Malta.json"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\Dr.Core.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\Dr.Core.pdb"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\Dr.Core.User.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\Dr.Core.User.pdb"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\Dr.Core.Web.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\Dr.Core.Web.pdb"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\Dr.Gaming.Data.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\Dr.Gaming.Data.pdb"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\Dr.Gaming.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\Dr.Gaming.Map.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\Dr.Gaming.Map.pdb"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\Dr.Gaming.pdb"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\Dr.Gaming.Reports.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\Dr.Gaming.Reports.pdb"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\Dr.Gaming.Smib.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\Dr.Gaming.Smib.pdb"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\Dr.WebApi.deps.json"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\Dr.WebApi.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\Dr.WebApi.exe"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\Dr.WebApi.pdb"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\Dr.WebApi.runtimeconfig.json"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\Dr.WebApi.staticwebassets.runtime.json"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\drWebApi.nsi"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\EFCore.BulkExtensions.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.HierarchyId.Abstractions.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.HierarchyId.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\Humanizer.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.Abstractions.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Common.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.Core.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Common.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocols.Json.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\Microsoft.Bcl.TimeProvider.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\Microsoft.JSInterop.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Host.win-x64.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Contracts.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\Nerdbank.Streams.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\Newtonsoft.Json.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\protobuf-net.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\protobuf-net.Grpc.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\System.Buffers.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\System.CodeDom.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\System.Diagnostics.EventLog.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\System.Drawing.Common.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\System.IO.Pipelines.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\System.Memory.Data.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketProtocol.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\System.Reflection.MetadataLoadContext.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\System.Security.Permissions.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\System.Text.Encoding.CodePages.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\System.Threading.Channels.dll"
File "..\bin\Debug\net6.0\System.Windows.Extensions.dll"

SectionEnd

######################################################################

Section -DesktopShortcut
${INSTALL_TYPE}
CreateShortCut "$DESKTOP\Dr.WebApi.lnk" "$INSTDIR\${MAIN_APP_EXE}" "" "$INSTDIR\${MAIN_APP_EXE}" 0
SectionEnd

######################################################################

Section -StartMenuShortcuts
${INSTALL_TYPE}
SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"

${If} $SILENT == 0
    CreateDirectory "$SMPROGRAMS\$SM_Folder"
    CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\$SM_Folder\Uninstall.lnk" "$INSTDIR\uninstall.exe"
    CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\$SM_Folder\Dr.WebApi.lnk" "$INSTDIR\${MAIN_APP_EXE}" "" "$INSTDIR\${MAIN_APP_EXE}" 0
${EndIf}
SectionEnd

######################################################################

    Section -Uninstaller
${INSTALL_TYPE}
DeleteRegKey ${REG_ROOT} "${UNINSTALL_PATH}"
RMDir /r "$INSTDIR"
Delete "$DESKTOP\Dr.WebApi.lnk"

${If} $SILENT == 0
    RMDir /r "$SMPROGRAMS\$SM_Folder"
${EndIf}
SectionEnd

######################################################################

Section -PostInstall
${INSTALL_TYPE}
SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"
WriteUninstaller "$INSTDIR\uninstall.exe"
WriteRegStr ${REG_ROOT} "${REG_APP_PATH}" "" "$INSTDIR\${MAIN_APP_EXE}"
WriteRegStr ${REG_ROOT} "${UNINSTALL_PATH}" "DisplayName" "${APP_NAME}"
WriteRegStr ${REG_ROOT} "${UNINSTALL_PATH}" "UninstallString" "$INSTDIR\uninstall.exe"
WriteRegStr ${REG_ROOT} "${UNINSTALL_PATH}" "InstallLocation" "$INSTDIR"
WriteRegStr ${REG_ROOT} "${UNINSTALL_PATH}" "Publisher" "${COMP_NAME}"
WriteRegStr ${REG_ROOT} "${UNINSTALL_PATH}" "DisplayVersion" "${VERSION}"
WriteRegStr ${REG_ROOT} "${UNINSTALL_PATH}" "Version" "${VERSION}"
WriteRegStr ${REG_ROOT} "${UNINSTALL_PATH}" "DisplayIcon" "$INSTDIR\${MAIN_APP_EXE}"
WriteRegStr ${REG_ROOT} "${UNINSTALL_PATH}" "HelpLink" ""
WriteRegStr ${REG_ROOT} "${UNINSTALL_PATH}" "URLInfoAbout" ""
SectionEnd

######################################################################

Function un.onInit
    ${If} $CMDLINE ~ "/S"
        SetSilent true
    ${EndIf}
FunctionEnd

The script is supposed to be a installer for my c# project. I tried blackbox ai and chatgpt but both are just going in circles and not giving any answers. My seniors and I have tried a ton of things but we cant figure it out, since this the first time using nsis and neither of us have any clue.

I assume the GetVersion macro has never worked. Where did you get it from?

Is GetVersion trying to read the fixed version info version or the string?
